# Why fiat-backed stablecoins have a decimal of more than 2?

Tags: stablecoins

Fiat-backed stablecoins usually have a decimal of 6 while fiat currencies only need a decimal of 2.

Is it necessary to have 6 for fiat-backed stablecoins and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> while fiat currencies only need a decimal of 2

In the consumer world maybe, but in the financial world it's usual to use more than two.

For example, in traditional trading, movements in the currency exchange markets are measured in "[pips](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pip.asp)" - or "percentage in point" - which is one-hundredth of one percent, or a value to the fourth decimal place (0.0001).

Further, there are 10 factional pips to a whole pip, meaning prices in traditional markets can be given to 5 decimal places.

When considering the above, having ERC20 stablecoins (i.e. USDC, USDT) use 6 dp makes slightly more sense.