# What's the reason all tokens have decimals?

Tags: solidity, tokens, decentralized-exchange

All of tokens have `decimals` property, e.g. [WBNB token](https://bscscan.com/address/0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c#readContract) has 18 decimals.

If there was a [dex](/questions/tagged/dex) pair using different decimals, then we would first need to divide both sides before we  calculate rates.

```
(token0 / pow(10, decimals0)) / (token1 / pow(10, decimals1))
```

What's the reason we need `decimals` as opposed to just having all tokens use the same base?

Is this is a limitation / optimization of [solidity](/questions/tagged/solidity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the reason all tokens have decimals?

They don't *have* to use decimals.

According to the [ERC-20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard description for `decimals`:

*"OPTIONAL - This method can be used to improve usability, but interfaces and other contracts MUST NOT expect these values to be present."*

For [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721):

*"...we find it contrived to require all ERC-721 implementations to support the decimals function."*

---

18 decimals equates to the equivalent translation from ETH -> wei, which is why it's so popular.

Other values do exist in the wild, such as 6 decimal places for USDT and USDC. (See: [Why fiat-backed stablecoins have a decimal of more than 2?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99896/why-fiat-backed-stablecoins-have-a-decimal-of-more-than-2))